# Re-opening iOS app through Url Scheme - State Preservation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm sending the user from my app to a browser then returning them to the app through my custom URL.  The problem is: All of my instance variables are empty once I return!  The interface is preserved (as expected since I used the Storyboard), but the values (of the textfields, instance variables, etc.) are inaccessible...they return null.

What's going on??

Comment: OK, figured it out!  The problem was that while handling the call in my app delegate's openURL method, I was calling my view controller's method in response; and I think, as a result, I was essentially creating a second instance of the view controller.  So now I'm using a notification instead of directly calling the method and it works like a charm. :)

Comment: Nice that you figured it out by yourself. Would it make sense to handle your URL call inside the app? Jumping out of the application and back inside feels like a workflow from the 90s ;)

Comment: Haha yeah, it's unfortunate, but I have no choice.  It's a charity app and Apple requires charity payments to be handled through a browser.  It's a shame though...way less cool...  I hope they change that rule soon.

Comment: You can't use a UIWebView?

Comment: @Liron No, for the reason I stated in my comment -- Apple doesn't allow payments to occur within charity apps for some strange reason that I don't understand at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(It's been a while since I had this problem, but here's what I think happened…)

While handling the return URL's call in my app delegate's openURL method, I attempted to call my view controller's method in response and did so by creating an instance of that method's view controller. Since I didn't access the current instance, I essentially created a blank, second instance of that view controller.

In this case, I ended up using an `NSNotification` instead of directly calling the method.  And I definitely think this is the most elegant solution.

But what I also could have done in retrospect, is access the current instance of the view controller which also happened to be the root view controller using:

```
UIViewController *controller = self.window.rootViewController;
```

Answer (score 2):

The response from the calls in the app delegate should preferably not call for any specific view controller, one of the following should be preferably used to modify data-

1.Blocks

2.NSUserDefaults or CoreData Database

3.Notifications

4.Shared Singleton instances

Comment: I appreciate you answering the question -- would have made my life a tiny bit easier ;) -- but the only relevant part of your response is #3, notifications, since I wasn't modifying data from the app delegate.  I was returning to the app through a custom URL and needed to pass along data.